# RxJava chainging observables on multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, realm, rx-java

I am working on application that utilizes RxJava, realm and retrofit.

I need to create very specific data processing chain. I need to perform Retrofit calls on the `io` scheduler, then process provided data on my custom single-thread `realm` scheduler, and then push results out to my ui on `mainThread` scheduler. I tried to do this by using multiple combinations of `observeOn` and `subscribeOn` but I can't get the middle part to execute on `realm` sheduler.

my goal is something like this

`scheduler: io ---------------> realm -----------------> mainthread
action   : retrofit call-----> database update -------> ui update`

How can I create such chain of observables, where each observable work is done on specific thread ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into the `Observable.observeOn(...)` method. This method will make sure all operations that happen after occur on the provided Scheduler.

To support your custom "realm" scheduler you will need to provide some way for RxJava to schedule work. If you're using a standard `Executor` (like `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` to support Realm's single-thread policy) then you can use `Schedulers.from(Executor)` to create a scheduler that will execute on that specific `Executor`.

```
ExecutorService realm = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Scheduler realmScheduler = Schedulers.from(realm);
Retrofit source;

source.call()
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
      .observeOn(realmScheduler)
      .map(DataBaseUpdate)
      .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
      .subscribe(UIUpdate)
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. upon further reading i finally understood the method to effectively compose all these actions on multiple threads

Comment: It should be `observeOn(realmScheduler)`, not `observeOn(realm)`

Comment: Indeed, adjusted it